# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in the main App.js file

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined. All code is defined in the main App.js file. Any solutions for this.

```
       <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={BottomNav}
                    options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        headerTitle: 'Home',
                        headerTitleStyle: { color: 'blue', fontWeight: 'bold' },
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                activeOpacity={0.5}
                                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PropertySearchScreen')}>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('./../assets/icons/search.png')}
                                    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your options of your navigator like this :

```
options={({navigation})=>{
                        headerShown: true,
                        headerTitle: 'Home',
                        headerTitleStyle: { color: 'blue', fontWeight: 'bold' },
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                activeOpacity={0.5}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PropertySearchScreen')}>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('./../assets/icons/search.png')}
                                    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginRight: 20 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ),
                    }}
```

Comment: I tried it. but it gives an error. Unexpected token